# Celery tasks not executing on Heroku using RabbitMQ

Tags: django, heroku, rabbitmq, celery

Our scheduling stack consists of a Django application with djCelery 3.1.9 and RabbitMQ, and hosted on Heroku with 3 Celery worker dynos and one scheduler.  We have scheduled tasks that are grouped to run together at different times.  We're finding that some tasks are not executing with the group.

Example:

1. From a celery inspect schedule this task is scheduled to run on April 3, 2014 at 19:40 UTC:

   - `{u'eta': u'2014-04-03T19:40:00+00:00', u'priority': 6, u'request': {u'name': u'api.tasks.close_event', u'time_start': None, u'id': u'c97813af-b070-4b67-8604-da572478e43e', u'kwargs': u'{}', u'args': u'[1002304]', u'delivery_info': {u'exchange': u'celery', u'redelivered': True, u'routing_key': u'celery', u'priority': None}, u'acknowledged': False, u'hostname': u'celery@3508e5c8-c6f7-46cb-be52-79405e9a5112', u'worker_pid': None}}`
2. There are 82 other tasks scheduled for the same time.
3. Each task takes about 1 second to run.
4. Out of the 83 tasks, 29 did not run.
5. A search of the celery inspect schedule output at 19:59 shows that task is no longer in the schedule.
6. The heroku log shows the following (local timezone is PST so 16:26:13 is 23:26:13 UTC).

`Apr 02 16:26:13 ogs-network app/worker.3: [2014-04-02 23:26:13,658: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: api.tasks.close_event[c97813af-b070-4b67-8604-da572478e43e] eta:[2014-04-03 19:40:00+00:00]`

1. So the task is scheduled but did not run at the expected time.
2. At 14:07:00 PST (21:07:00 UTC), the worker was restarted and the task executed.  From the heroku log:

`Apr 03 14:07:09 ogs-network app/worker.2: [2014-04-03 21:07:09,596: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: api.tasks.close_event[c97813af-b070-4b67-8604-da572478e43e] eta:[2014-04-03 19:40:00+00:00]
Apr 03 14:07:10 ogs-network app/worker.2: [2014-04-03 21:07:10,490: INFO/MainProcess] Task api.tasks.close_event[c97813af-b070-4b67-8604-da572478e43e] succeeded in 0.372298751958s: None`

---

We feel the task is getting scheduled and accepted but not running at the expected time.

Some other settings that we use:

`CELERY_ACKS_LATE = FALSE (default)
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 4 (default)
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"`

Looking for any and all assistance.  Thanks for any help in advance.

===================================

UPDATE: we discovered a long-running task that was interfering with the quick tasks that got queued up behind it. They are scheduled to retry and eventually run out of wait time due to the long running task. By changing the long-running task to smaller, repeating tasks (it does what it has to do and then reschedules), our problems seems to have gone away. Will post again if the problem arises - for now, we are marking this as resolved.

Comment: Just as a follow up, I believe these are ETA tasks, correct? Meaning, they are dynamically scheduled, not using the celery annotations for a periodic task.

Comment: It would likely be helpful to add some a code snippet showing how the task is scheduled.

Comment: Are the clocks in sync? This is a requirement if you need (better) accuracy.

Comment: Yes, confirmed that the clocks are in sync between all 3 workers.

Comment: UPDATE:  we discovered a long-running task that was interfering with the quick tasks that got queued up behind it.  They are scheduled to retry and eventually run out of wait time due to the long running task.

By changing the long-running task to smaller, repeating tasks (it does what it has to do and then reschedules), our problems seems to have gone away.

Will post again if the problem arises - for now, we are marking this as resolved.